# Pull most recent two records Grouped by Contact

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am looking to create a SELECT query where it takes my data below and returns only the last two Purchase IDs per Contact as two separate columns.
Things to take into account:

1. In a case where there is only one Purchase ID (Contact '123' in the case below), then just show that one record.
2. There could be two purchase IDs for the same contact that share the same last date (like with Contact '700' in my example below).
3. In a case where there are more than two purchase ID's on the same date, then just take the two max purchase ID's as 'Purchase ID' and 'Purchase ID 2'

[image: Data]

[image: Results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple conditional aggregation in concert with row_number() should do the trick

```
Select ContactID
      ,PurchaseID  = max(case when RN=1 then Purchase ID end)
      ,PurchaseID2 = max(case when RN=2 then Purchase ID end)
 From (
        Select *
              ,RN = row_number() over (partition by ContactID order by PurchaseDate desc)
         From  YourTable
      ) A
 Group By ContactID
```